# How about a new stack exchange site about understanding women?

Tags: feature-request

No.. seriously! :)

Think about it! Different cultures, different points of view and a mature community.
If just one relationship could be saved it would be worth it!

Comment: Yes, but... Where are we going to find a mature community?

Comment: seriously! No.. :)

Comment: If you really think a Q&A proposal is a good one, then you should suggest it at area51.stackexchange.com to see if the community agrees.

Answer (score 8):

People who would turn to a Q&A website to learn to understand women are precisely the ones who shouldn't be breeding.

Comment: That is *not* what it says in my copy of "Women for Dummies."

Comment: What? Wait, there are women *for* dummies?  Ah, yes, Charlie Sheen, there must be.

Comment: Although, to be honest, people who would turn to a Q&A site to learn to understand women already have a low chance at producing offspring anyway.

Comment: @Bill: Very relevant for a guy who claims to have rep-capped every day of his honeymoon.

Comment: @mmyers: Now that we have the new reputation display, I see that I missed it on two days. :(  (Also, I'm really irritated with myself over the number of times I've scored ~175.)